# SonarLint Rule regarding Files.notExists

Tags: java, io, sonarqube, nio

SonarLint is saying that i should use `if(programFolder.toFile().exists)` instead of `if(Files.exists(programFolder))`. I always thought it is encouraged to use the newer nio Path instead of io File.

Can someone explain me why SonarList encourages the use of the file instead of the path in this case?

Comment: It took me 1 minute to find this, using google: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/pull/1009/files#diff-cc16f87fc630cd3cca1b8b05093433c2

Comment: You also have the description of the rule accessible from SonarLint directly if you click on the issue on the list of issues. Here is a link to the description of the rule https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3725  Please have a look at the last section that links to two JDK bugs explaining what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the description of the rule accessible from SonarLint directly if you click on the issue on the list of issues. Here is a link to the description of the [rule](http://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS3725).

If you look at the last section of the description that links to two JDK bugs explaining what is going on. Basically, this implementation performs poorly as it fills up needless stacks with errors when the file does not exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason the SonarLint report window in eclipse is empty. But the line is highlighted in the editor und shown in eclipses normal issues window. So i cant use the rule description link in the report.